# aggregate doesn't provide information I expect and group by duplicate records

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am creating a materialized view coming form two tables.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW poly_mv AS (
   SELECT p.id,
          p.name,
          p.code,
          p.descrip,
          p.geom,
          string_agg(distinct t.id::text, ',') as boundary_1_id,
          string_agg(distinct t.boundary_2, ',') as boundary_2, 
    string_agg(distinct t.country, ',') as country      
   FROM boundary p,
        territories t
   GROUP BY p.id,
            p.name,
            p.code,
            p.descrip,
            p.geom
);
```

but it results in an accumulation for each row of all the values i.e. for country, all the rows have `England, Wales`  instead of England or wales depending of each polygon as it happens in the boundary table where each row has England or Wales.

If I add to `group by` a `t.country` line, it appear the values according to country, but it duplicate the polygons and create one row for Wales and other for England.

How can just obtain the country information for each polygon correctly?

Comment: Hey there. Could you provide some data sample and the exact expected result set? Preferably in a fiddle ;)

Comment: You are cross joining boundary and territories.  You'll need to figure out what the actual relation is between the tables and do a different type of join.

Comment: @JimJones I have tried but errors appears when appending to sql fiddle i ahave tried to cnvert to ascii but as one of the columns have geom it doesnt work well. some idea about how can I provided some data?

Comment: @jr.gcj take this fiddle I created for you and add the data in the insert statements: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8e90c698e7547de799e65e13aac4ce9d

Comment: @JimJones one of the tables comes from materialized view I have tried to export some data but I cannot. the otehr table I could https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b88f02d377b9257c9a9ebe59b83723d3

Comment: @jr.gcj your insert statements invalid. You do not need to post that much information, a simple minimal reproducible example would suffice. The query in your question joins two tables without any criteria. Is it a spatial join? If so, tell us which one (intersects, overlaps, contains, etc..)

Comment: @JimJones I have been researching and thanks to your comment I realize what was wrong. If you send an answer I can flag you as the correct answer if you want. Thanks very much for your advise

Comment: @jr.gcj I'm glad it could help you. I added a more elaborated answer to my previous comment :)

Comment: Totally urelated, but: the parentheses around the SELECT are useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query in your question joins two tables without any criteria (cross join). In order to spatially join both tables, you must first identify how they relate and chose the best operation, e.g. `ST_Contains`, `ST_Intersects`, `ST_Touches` etc... the list is pretty long. After you identify the spatial operation, just add it in a `JOIN`, e.g..

```
SELECT * FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON ST_Contains(t1.geom,t2.geom)
```

or in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM t1,t2
WHERE ST_Contains(t1.geom,t2.geom)
```